# How to solve this this bad operand types for binary operator

Tags: java, operators, operands

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for(int i=1;i < sc.hasNext();i++){
            System.out.print(i+sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}


Solution.java:10: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
        for(int i=1;i < sc.hasNext();i++){
                      ^
  first type:  int
  second type: boolean
1 error
```

Comment: Remove the `i < ` part!?

Comment: `sc.hasNext()` returns a boolean. You're asking the equivalent of `1 < true` or `1 < false`, which is non-sensical, hence, error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hasNext()` method returns true if this scanner has another token in its input, else if it has no more tokens then it returns false. And we can't compare `int` with `boolean`. Hence it's sufficient to use `hasNext()` as a terminating condition.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for (int i=1;sc.hasNext();i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i+sc.nextLine());
        }
        /** ALT:
        int i = 1;
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.print(i+sc.nextLine());
        }
        **/
    }
}
```